# python regular expression to remove u'some text' from the unicode output

Tags: python, regex

I have a running application which has been storing u'text' into all database fields by mistake. I need to create a script now to read these fields and replace u'text' with text.

Can anyone help me on how can i write such regular expression in python that would read the beginning of the string which starts with u' and end of string with ends with ' and then replace them with nothing.. I tried several approaches but am very bad around regular expressions.

Any help would be very much appreciated,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
import re
re.sub("^u'(.*)'$",r'\1',"u'text'")
-> text
```

This will work on a single value string without leading/trailing characters (e.g. "u'text'").

If you want replace all occurences of u'text' within a string, you can do this instead:

```
re.sub("u'([^']*)'",r'\1',STRING)
```

For instance:

```
re.sub("u'([^']*)'",r'\1',"u'value1',u'value2',u'value3'")
-> value1,value2,value3
```

Comment: hi jsedev, thanks. It worked out, but am having strange problem when i used it inside a loop return ', '.join(re.sub("^u'(.*)'$", r'\1', i) for i in value_list) it will only work on the first element

Comment: You need to use a list comprehension: `', '.join([re.sub("^u'(.*)'$", r'\1', i) for i in value_list])`

Comment: What's `value_list` then? because this works for me: `', '.join([re.sub("^u'(.*)'$", r'\1', i) for i in ["u'value1'","u'value2'","u'value3'"]])` -> `'value1, value2, value3``.

Comment: ops, i had a small typo.. Thanks mate, very much appreciated

Comment: Careful, if you accidentally stored something like `u'\u3edc'` in the database, you will put `\u3edc` in the database instead of the correct encoding for that character.

Answer (score 3):

Note that you may have some strings that are delimited by `u" "` instead, if the string contains single quotes. Also, there may be escape sequences. `ast.literal_eval` can handle all that for you:

```
from ast import literal_eval

def convert(original):
    try:
        result = literal_eval(original)
        if isinstance(result, unicode):
            return result
    except ValueError:
        pass
    return original
```